# How can I add a new item to my enum list in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity

I have a list of enums. I want to add a new item to it without scripting to make them more easily modifiable for game designers.
I made an inventory system and I want to define the type of an item. For an example apple is a type of *food* and stone is a type of *object*.

Is there a way to group these items in the inspector?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public const string[] typesStrings = {"Player", "Prop", "Enemy"};
    [System.Serializable]
    public class TypeList
    {
        public enum types
        {
            PLAYER = 0,
            PROP = 1,
            ENEMY = 2
        }

    };

    // MonoBehaviour class
    public TypeList.types selectedType;

    public void Start()
    {
        string selected = TypeList.typesStrings[(int)selectedType];
    }
}
```

This, however, gives me the following error:

> Assets/grouping.cs(5,31): error CS0134: A constant `grouping.typesStrings' of reference type`string[]' can only be initialized with null

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. I removed the second question from your post. But feel free to post it again as a new question. You can retrieve the text and image from the edit history.

Comment: To work around that particular error, I usually define my constant arrays as `static readonly` which is not *quite* constant (the array contents are still mutable) but close enough for my purposes.

Comment: @DMGregory enums have many problems so I use ScriptableObjects instead.

Answer (score 6):

you can use System.Serializable

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class grouping: MonoBehaviour {
    [System.Serializable]
    public class class1{
    public enum myEnum {one,two,three};
    public myEnum[] row;
    public string name;
    public int price;
    }
    public class1[] array;
}
```

[useful link 1](http://va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist/) for more information:

make your lists functional with ReorderableList

[image]

[useful link 2](http://www.ryan-meier.com/blog/?p=87)
Custom Editors in Unity3D – Part 8: CustomEditor

[image]

Unity Editor: Enum Flags as Toggle Buttons
[useful link 3](http://www.sharkbombs.com/2015/02/17/unity-editor-enum-flags-as-toggle-buttons/)
[image]